# CMD command to open a file using link

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Below is my batch file script

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%b in (C:\COST\Programlink.txt) do (
%%b
pause
)
```

And in the **programlink.txt** as mentioned in the above batch command I have the link of the file I want to open

```
"D:\COST\Mustafa Batch files\Batch files\1.txt"
```

But when I run the batchfile script it shows the below error

```
'"D:\COST\Mustafa' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable command or batch file.
Press any key to continue...
```

But when i enter the below command directly into the **CMD prompt** it works fine.

```
 "D:\COST\Mustafa Batch files\Batch files\1.txt"
```

I just want to open **1.txt** file using my batch script I mentioned above.
I can't identify my mistake. Please help me to right my batchfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the modified batchfile as below by using **"usebackq delims="**  and works well

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in (C:\COST\Programlink.txt) do (
%%b
pause
)
```

But this is only one half of my batchfile. I shall proceed further and will come back if face any further problems.

And It has worked well.